# Install custom version of application from ClickOnce deployment

Tags: visual-studio, .net-4.0, clickonce

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

There is one version of application for production (1.0.0.0) and other for dev (1.0.2.1).

I have other small console application that does some stuff (check perms, make ssh tunnels, etc) that in the end runs main application, this application knows version that user wants to launch.

How can I run different version of main application from this point. I already implemented:

```
    using (var host = new InPlaceHostingManager(deploymentUri, false))
    {
        GetApplicationManifest(host);
        AssertApplicationRequirements(host);
        DownloadApplication(host);
    }
```

but this does not leave me place to choose which version I would like to launch. I'm thinking about implementing my own downloader that could retrieve manifest for certain version and download files based on it to custom installation folder and run it from there.

Maybe there is better way?
Thanks, Jakub